# Affine algebraic curves with a certain type of reflectional symmetry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves

Let $p(x,y)$ be a polynomial defining an affine algebraic plane curve. I'm interested in such $p$ with the property that $p(x,y)=-p(y,x)$. I've tried and failed to find references for plane curves with this type of symmetry, but this seems like a natural enough condition that it must be well-studied.

What are some references/key words/terms I should consult to learn more about such curves?

Comment: Any such polynomial is of the form $f(x+y, xy)(x-y)$ for some polynomial $f$ in 2 variables.

Comment: @Mohan: Thanks for your comment. Do you know of any references that study these curves?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. As I said above these curves are reducible, with a line $x-y=0$ as a component and the other part is symmetric. Symmetric curves are any curve `pulled' back via $k[x+y,xy]\subset k[x,y]$ and thus more or less as complex as any curve in the plane.